# F5 Load balancer over web server

Tags: load, webserver, load-balancing, f5, big-ip

I have to derive the infrastructure set up for my company. I was confused if a web server(Apache) can be replaced by F5 load balancer.
Are all the capabilities a web server possess/handles can be handled/possessed by F5 load balancer.
What i know is web server will safe gaurd the app server other than serving the static data.

Even the re-write rules of Apache can written in F5 load balancer as iRules.

With the above I am seeing the necessity of having a web server in the application architecture.

However would like to hear from to understand if I my perception is right/wrong.

Suggestions please..

Comment: it really depends on your requirements for a web server. For some deployments, absolutely, you can eliminate the tier altogether. For others, it still makes sense to have that tier.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Jason's comment, if you're serving up publicly consumable content, you should use Apache.  Your developers would normally not have access to the BIG-IP so any content management requirements would be hindered by placing publicly served pages on the BIG-IP.

If you're only using BIG-IP for rewrites, redirects, traffic manipulation, and any SSL/TLS management, BIG-IP would be an appropriate place for this as long as your dev teams don't require frequent management of these functions.

This is really an opinion question but standard practices do host web servers behind the BIG-IP for content layer presentation.